# Can't seem to keep a redis counter correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I have a few counters getting stored in REDIS that get updated upon state changes in customer.rb. The things I need to store are:

1) count of customers associated with a user (user has_many customers)
2) count of customers that have a state of (using aasm_state) 'open' or 'claimed'
3) count of customers that have a state of (using aasm_state) 'open

Whenever a customer's state changes, I increment/decrement the redis counters accordingly. However, no matter what i've tried, the counts seems to always be off after a certain time period.

I'm using Sidekiq but I don't think it's a concurrency issue since REDIS shouldn't be subject to problems of concurrency, right?

Here's my count updater method:

```
  def reset_stats
    if aasm_state_was == 'open' && aasm_state == 'claimed' # open => assigned
      # update company and user
      user.redis_increment_my_customers_length
      company.redis_decrement_open_customers_length

    elsif user_id_changed? && aasm_state_was == 'claimed' && aasm_state == 'claimed' # assigned => assigned
      # update users (assigner and assignee)
      user_was = User.find(user_id_was)
      user.redis_increment_my_customers_length
      user_was.redis_decrement_my_customers_length

    elsif aasm_state_was == 'claimed' && aasm_state == 'closed' # assigned => closed
      # update company and user
      user_was = User.find(user_id_was)
      user_was.redis_decrement_my_customers_length
      company.redis_decrement_all_customers_length

    elsif aasm_state_was == 'closed' && aasm_state == 'claimed' # closed => assigned
      # update company and user
      user.redis_increment_my_customers_length
      company.redis_increment_all_customers_length

    elsif aasm_state_was == 'closed' && aasm_state == 'open' # closed => open
      # update company
      company.redis_increment_all_customers_length
      company.redis_increment_open_customers_length

    elsif aasm_state_was == 'open' && aasm_state == 'closed' # open => closed
      # update company
      company.redis_decrement_all_customers_length
      company.redis_decrement_open_customers_length

    end
```

and in user.rb:

```
def redis_length_key
    "my_customers_length_for_#{id}"
  end

  def set_my_customers_length(l)
    RED.set(redis_length_key, l)
    l.to_i
  end

  def redis_increment_my_customers_length
    RED.get(redis_length_key) ? RED.incr(redis_length_key) : my_customers_length
  end

  def redis_decrement_my_customers_length
    RED.get(redis_length_key) ? RED.decr(redis_length_key) : my_customers_length
  end

  def my_customers_length
    if l = RED.get(redis_length_key)
      l.to_i
    else
      set_my_customers_length(my_customers.length)
    end
  end
```

and in company.rb:

```
def open_customers
    customers.open
  end

  def redis_open_length_key
    "open_customers_length_for_#{id}"
  end

  def set_open_customers_length(l)
    RED.set(redis_open_length_key, l)
    l.to_i
  end

  def redis_increment_open_customers_length
    RED.get(redis_open_length_key) ? RED.incr(redis_open_length_key) : open_customers_length
  end

  def redis_decrement_open_customers_length
    RED.get(redis_open_length_key) ? RED.decr(redis_open_length_key) : open_customers_length
  end

  def open_customers_length
    if l = RED.get(redis_open_length_key)
      return l.to_i
    else
      set_open_customers_length(open_customers.length)
    end
  end

  def redis_all_length_key
    "all_customers_length_for_#{id}"
  end

  def set_all_customers_length(l)
    RED.set(redis_all_length_key, l)
    l
  end

  def redis_increment_all_customers_length
    RED.get(redis_all_length_key) ? RED.incr(redis_all_length_key) : all_customers_length
  end

  def redis_decrement_all_customers_length
    RED.get(redis_all_length_key) ? RED.decr(redis_all_length_key) : all_customers_length
  end

  def all_customers_length
    if l = RED.get(redis_all_length_key)
      l.to_i
    else
      set_all_customers_length(open_or_claimed_customers.length)
    end
  end

  def open_or_claimed_customers
    customers.open_or_claimed
  end
```

Is there a better pattern for what I'm trying to accomplish? This has been extremely frustrating because the counts always seem to become incorrect after a while. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race condition between the time you call `set_my_customers_length(my_customers_length + 1)` and the time you call `RED.set(redis_open_length_key, l)`.

1. Two processes start.
2. my_customers_length is 5 when that first call is made for both processes.
3. First process makes the second call and sets Redis to 6.
4. Second process makes the second call and sets Redis to 6 again.
5. Redis value should in fact be 7.

Consider using Redis' INCR and DECR functions to atomically update the values.

- http://redis.io/commands/incr
- http://redis.io/commands/decr
- http://redis.io/commands/incrby
- http://redis.io/commands/decrby

Comment: this is an excellent suggestion, thank you. I fixed my code and deployed and an hour later...the counts are off by 1 again. i am checking the counts randomly with the method I provided in the EDIT. is there anything else that could be going on? it's possible the counts were off while i deployed, so i reset them and will check again shortly. (updated my original question with your update)

Comment: also, if it helps, the latest reset showed that the redis count was +1 greater than the actual counts

Comment: My guess is you have a race condition somewhere else then or the incr/decr code is being called more than once.  You'll have to trace all the paths to see.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition here:

```
RED.get(redis_all_length_key) ? RED.incr(redis_all_length_key) : all_customers_length
```

You cannot do any logic between reading from and writing to Redis.